# Laravel 5, class not found exception for a seeder

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using a seeder to seed a database table usinfg faker to generate fake data.
I tried this for a couple of tables it worked just fine, now I'm getting class not found exception even though the class exists in the proper name space.
here's the code for the seeder

```
    <?php

    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

    class FoodDrinksCategorySeeder extends Seeder {
        public function run(){
             $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();
             DB::table('category')->delete();
             for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
                \App\FoodDrinksCategory::create([
                     'name_en' => $faker->name,
                      'discribtion_en' => $faker->name,
                      'name_ar' => $faker->name,
                      'discribtion_ar' => $faker->name
                ]);
        }
   }  }
```

and here's the Model code for

```
  namespace App;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class FoodDrinksCategory extends Model{

      protected $table = 'food_drinks_category';


      protected $fillable = 
              ['name_en','name_ar','decription_ar','decription_en'];

      public function drinks(){
          return $this->hasMany('App\Drink', 'food_drinks_types_id');
      }


      public function meals(){
         return $this->hasMany('App\Meal', 'food_drinks_types_id');
      }
 }
```

when calling `php artisan db:seed --class=FoodDrinksCategorySeeder`
I get the following `[ReflectionException]
  Class FoodDrinksCategorySeeder does not exist`

Comment: Did you run `composer dumpautoload`?

Comment: This solved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @aynber how many times will I forget :D?